# Why does this CSS transition not work?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have code on an element for transition:

```
#zlatest .zreader-toggle-fetch-inner {
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

This matches one element. On this element I switch between these classes and hoped to see a smooth transition, but the change is immediate:

```
.zReader-requested {
    height: 50px;
}
.zreader-received {
    height: auto;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use max-height instead of height.

Comment: There was a link to another answer. This was removed which was unexpected for me. Unfortunately that mean I have lost it. So here is a question again - which might have been answered there, I do not know. Why does max-height work instead?

Comment: You can't transition to a implicit height value

Comment: Ah, now I see that @NiettheDarkAbsol has a link to the same solution that was removed. Thanks. And I believe I understand what you said now, c-misura. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented transition yet. What you have done was switching the classes of elements, so the effect took place immediately.

What you need to do is to start the animation when something happens, not just switching classes.

Comment: Also, you can't transition to `height: auto`

Comment: Thanks @Toan, but I do not understand what you mean here. It works switching classes if I use max-height.